# React + Immutable - Implementing shouldComponentUpdate with shallow equality

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

so I'm using react and I'm taking the approach of using Immutable data in my project with facebook's immutable.js library.

I know that React is way faster than every other library because it updates only the neccesarry DOM, I knew that it does a reconciliation process before updating and that in the process it creates Virtual DOM and compares them, but I never really knew how it knows what to update.
So I did some research and its true, the reconciling algorithm of react is really awesome and saves time, but then something hit me, where does the shouldComponentUpdate method enters?
So react invokes the shouldComponentUpdate for each component and if it returns true, the react does the reconciling process which includes creating virtual doms and comparing them.
So why shouldn't we implement the SCU method for every component? Well react also gives you an answer that includes comparing mutable object and that the equality in this cases should be a deep one, and that would take too long, so you might as well not implement it.

And here is the part where I ask my question, if my entire data on my project is in fact immutable, why shouldn't I implements the SCU with a simple shallow equality on all of my components? This way we spare the reconcile process and our app will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you have SCU method and if it returns true, `React` creates virtual DOM and compares it with existing DOM. If they are equal, nothing happens, however, still that costs for creating virtual DOM. On the other hand, if SCU method returns false, it skips the component and subcomponents and stays same (virtual DOM is not created).

Implementing SCU component like the sample code below is the most efficient way if all props are gathered under `values` key as Immutable and there is no state in the component,

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return !Immutable.is(this.props.values, nextProps.values)
}
```